# How to search terms with wildcard in elasticsearch using querystringquery

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following query

```
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "*036-1922*",
      "default_field" : "partNumber"
    }
  }
```

But it's returning null,even though i have documents which contain 036-1922

looks like its checking for * also when we have special character in the given term for explame here here - in 036-1922.

How to over come this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found solution ,Issue was solved by using

"query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "\*036-192\*",
      "default_field" : "partNumber"
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. Have you tried escaping the dash, like so: `036\-1922`?
2. Wildcards are really bad for performance, especially leading ones. Check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) out for more info

Comment: Yes i have tried with 036\-1922 while forming query only its giving an exception as bad string